# Making parameters required by using a function call as a default value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, parameters

ECMAScript 6 introduced [default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters). The default value can be any expression, so you can use it to make a function throw an error when a parameter is not supplied:

```js
const mandatory = (name) => {
  throw new Error(`The ${name} parameter is mandatory`);
};

const foo = (bar = mandatory('bar')) => {
  // some code
};

foo(42); // Works fine.
foo(); // Error: The bar parameter is mandatory
```

What are the advantages and disadvantages of this? Is it a good practice, or an abuse of default parameters?

Comment: This looks fine to me.  I do not think it is "functionally" any different than checking against undefined in the function itself.  All I would recommend is that you keep it consistent across your code base.  Good conventions will make your code easier to maintain.  (Also, verify that the browsers you support have implemented this functionality.)

Comment: @Caleb I'm not asking whether it is functionally different, but whether it is (more) readable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are abusing the functionality a little bit.

The point of default parameters is providing a value which make sense in case calls to this function don't pass some definite value for that parameter.

There is a big overlap between not passing a definite value and forgetting a mandatory parameter, but there is a difference: you can pass `undefined`.

Your code will throw if the function is called with `undefined`:

```
const mandatory = (name) => {
  throw new Error(`The ${name} parameter is mandatory`);
};
const foo = (bar = mandatory('bar')) => {
  // some code
};
foo(undefined); // Error: The bar parameter is mandatory
```

In this case complaining about the parameter being mandatory is misleading, because a parameter has been passed indeed.

`undefined` might not be an allowed value, but in this case you should check the value and complain about its type.

If you only want to check if an argument has been passed or not, using a normal function and checking `arguments.length` may be a better idea.

See for example the behavior of `DOMParser#parseFromString`, which in my opinion is more helpful:

```
var p = new DOMParser();
p.parseFromString();                     // TypeError: Not enough arguments
p.parseFromString(undefined);            // TypeError: Not enough arguments
p.parseFromString(undefined, undefined); // TypeError: Argument 2 'undefined' is not a valid value
```

Comment: How is passing `undefined` as an argument different from calling a function without arguments? The standard way to check if an arguments has been passed or not is to compare the parameter to `undefined`, which works exactly as using default parameters.

Comment: @Gothdo Passing undefined may behave differently than passing no argument, that's the point. For example, compare `Array()` and `Array(undefined)`.